# Alternative to hexdigest that uses all 26 letters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash, md5

I'm writing an application that makes calls to various APIs.  Each API does its own logging, and I'd like to make it easy to trace a transaction across all the various logfiles.

To do this, I create a unique(ish) string when a transaction starts, log it, and pass that string to the other APIs so they can all include it in their logging.

This is the code I'm using:

```
s = '%s %s' % (username, datetime.datetime.now())
token = hashlib.md5(s.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
```

This is working well, however there is room for improvement.  `hexdigest()` (obviously) only uses hex characters, i.e. `0-9` and `a-f`.  I don't care too much if I get an occasional token collision, but I'd like to avoid it as much as possible.  Is there a similar function that will use all 26 letters?

Comment: Is a UUID an option here?

Comment: @SimeonVisser UUID appears to have the same limitation of only using hex digits.

Comment: @PatrickArtner base64 produces similar outputs for similar inputs, which I don't want.

Comment: You are conflating two distinct problems. 1) hash functions and their collision probabilities, and 2) encoding the result of the hash function. I'm unsure which problem(s) you're actually concerned about.

Comment: @JamesKPolk I was assuming that a larger output address space would result in fewer hash collisions.  Is that not the case?

Comment: Two different problems. The "output address space" is *solely* a property of the hash function. The way the output is encoded is *solely* a property of the encoder.

Answer (score 2):

Try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii85 and its URL-safe variants for a more dense representation.

You will have to encode raw bytes, of course. (Also, MD5 is a poor choice from crypto perspective, SHA2 is way better.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I didn't know about this.  But I really want something that's a _hash_ rather than an _encoding_ -- i.e. I want similar inputs to produce wildly different outputs.

Comment: [SHA2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) is a hashing algorithm, exactly as you describe. You're using username and effectively salting it with current time; both parts are easy to guess and thus one can create a token like yours. OTOH you seem to not be using it for auth purposes, so MD5 is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could hash your data, then encode the hash with base64 rather than taking the hex digest directly:

```py
s = '%s %s' % (username, datetime.datetime.now())
digest = hashlib.md5(s.encode('utf-8')).digest()
token = base64.b64encode(digest)
```

This uses all 26×2+10 = 62 alphanumeric characters, plus `+` and `/`.

Your implementation might produce something like this:

```
d88cc7dea0fee57975187d4b30950f7b
```

Encoding it with base64 reduces the length slightly:

```
2IzH3qD+5Xl1GH1LMJUPew==
```

However, if you want to avoid *collisions*, you need to increase the length of the digest – so use a hash function like SHA512, for instance, instead of MD5, or even just generate a random number!

Answer (score 0):

Question makes sense to me as I have the same requirement - I want as unique as possible a key that is under 250 characters long.

Building on ash's answer, `hashlib.sha512` is the method in the standard Python library that generates the longest hash, so is presumably most collision-proof (but happy to be corrected).

```
base64.b64encode(hashlib.sha512(force_bytes(s)).digest()).decode()
```

Generates an 88 character alphanumeric such as:

```
'mKMA51TaQedePb5pdm+pd96y1BNldEAKwbjT1eebF0cQNcZkiVs+XWDhKtVj8IxIfvTrqq2yQ4l/zHW/brbjjA=='
```

The final `==` is common to all hashes, so I presume could be stripped? If so, 38^86 = 7,267,571,431,315,762,176,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000.

Using `hashlib.sha512(...).hexdigest()` generates a 128 character string (with the same sha512 collision risk).

base64 of an MD5 generates a 24 character string, and the hexdigest is a 32 character string, (both with the same md5 collision risk).